# Prove that $ \int_{a}^{b} |f| = 0 \iff \int_{a}^{b} f^2 = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Suppose that two functions $|f|, f^2 $ are **Riemann integrable** function on $[a, b] \in \mathbb R$.

I want to show that

$$ \int_{a}^{b} |f| = 0 \iff \int_{a}^{b} f^2 = 0 $$

Remember that we don't know whether the function $ f $ is ***continuous or not***.

If $ f $ is continuous, it is very easy.
But i want to prove that $ f $ is not continuous.

I have been tried a lot of methods, but i can't prove it. Plz help

Comment: If $|f| \leq M$ then $0 \leq \int f^{2}\leq M\int|f|=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But I have a additional question that how $ f^2 $ integrable implies $ |f| $ integrable?

Comment: And for the converse, use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality on the product $|f|\cdot 1.$ But really, one should just prove generally that the integral of a non-negative function is sero if and only if the set of points where the function doesn’t vanish has measure zero (this is possible to prove even in the Riemann integral setting, prior to any measure theory exposure).

Comment: @Geetha I think OP might be referring to regularity rather than finiteness of the integral (which is clear since by definition the functions involved are bounded and clearly $f$ is bounded if and only if $f^2$ is). To OP: one could formulate a general theorem about when a composition is Riemann integrable, but the proof I know isn’t elementary: it uses Lebesgue’s criterion for Riemann integrability. But this is why you’re given that the functions are Riemann integrable, so you don’t have to worry about this.

Comment: @monotoniclife Why would you need that in this exercise? As I see from the question, you assume from the beginning that both functions are integrable.